# How to ask git if the repository is in a conflict stage?

Tags: git, state, status

There are a lot of ways to see, as a human, whether the repository has conflicts that need to be resolved or not.

However, I am looking for a way to check this in a script. That is, to check whether the repository is at a good shape to start doing something to it, or it is at a stage where the user has to fix the conflicts.

I can think of a way such as the following:

```
__git_ps1 "%s" | grep MERGING > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "In merge state"
```

However, I suspect this is not a recommended method. First because `__git_ps1` starts with `__` and as a C programmer I tend to think it's not for my use, and second that I'm guessing there is a more proper way like:

```
git repo-status --is-merging
```

which would have the return value, or something like that.

So, how do I ask git (as a script) if the repository is at a merging state?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `git status` or similar will be slow on a large repository, as it needs to check the entire working copy's status, as well as the index.  We're only interested in the index, so we can use much quicker commands that will just check the index state.

Specifically, we can use `git ls-files --unmerged`.  That command will produce no output if there are no files in a conflicted state, and something like the below if there are:

```
$ git ls-files --unmerged
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 1       filename
100644 4a58007052a65fbc2fc3f910f2855f45a4058e74 2       filename
100644 65b2df87f7df3aeedef04be96703e55ac19c2cfb 3       filename
```

So we can just check if that file produces any output: `[[ -z $(git ls-files --unmerged) ]]`.  That command will give a return code of zero if the repository is clean, and non-zero if the repository has conflicts.  Replace `-z` with `-n` for the inverse behaviour.

You could add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    conflicts = ![[ -n $(git ls-files --unmerged) ]]
    list-conflicts = "!cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u"
```

This will give behaviour like the following:

```
$ git st
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git conflicts && echo 'Conflicts exist' || echo 'No conflicts'
No conflicts

$ git merge other-branch
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git conflicts && echo 'Conflicts exist' || echo 'No conflicts'
Conflicts exist

$ git list-conflicts
file
```

(The `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` part of the second alias means you only get a list of the conflicting files in the current directory, not for the entire repository.)

Comment: That's good to know. I indeed went with the `git status` solution since I thought I might as well make sure the repository is clean, besides having merge conflicts, but this is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
$ if ! grep -Eq '^(U.|.U|AA|DD)' <(git status --porcelain)
> then # no merge conflicts
> else # merge conflicts
> fi
```

Comment: That almost works, but you also need to expect add and delete conflicts.

Comment: Exactly. In my test repo, the conflict is `AA file`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted the other mostly because he has less reputation.

Comment: `DD` shouldn't be a conflict. If both branches deleted the same file, who cares! Not sure how you would end up in that state anyway.

Comment: I just got it off the man page, it doesn't make sense to me either but it's listed so I figure why not check

Comment: http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing "The interface (input, output, set of options and the semantics) to these low-level commands are meant to be a lot more stable than Porcelain level commands, because these commands are primarily for scripted use. The interface to Porcelain commands on the other hand are subject to change in order to improve the end user experience."

Comment: Your regex is broken, the `^` applies only to the first case, `U.`. Any files containing `U`, `AA` or `DD` will also make it consider the repository as having merge conflicts. Using `grep` is also much more common: `if ! git status --porcelain | grep -Eq '^(U.|.U|AA|DD)'; then ...`

Comment: Also note the `q[exit-code]` command in `sed` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest Fixed, thanks. I somehow spaced on `grep -q` for a long while, is it too late to say "I knew that"?

Comment: You still need to either swap the if/else blocks or add a `!` before the command to negate the return code (in my partial example I did the latter to leave the blocks untouched, but would generally use a more natural block ordering). You should also be able to negate with `-v`, i.e. `grep -Evq <pattern>`, but I haven't checked if it's as widely supported so I went with the safer choice.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest gakk. Fixed that plus made it work for people who don't run with lastpipe, *thank you* for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
$ git merge origin/master
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      file
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git status -s         
UU file
```

You can tell you are in a merge state because it tells you that a file has 2 modifications and both are unmerged. Actually, if you have `XY file` where `X` and `Y` are both letters, you probably have a conflict that needs resolving.

Comment: So, any different `X` and `Y` means conflict? Or at least one of them should be `U`? Or, you mean any line that passes `^[A-Z][A-Z] ` shows a conflict?

Comment: I think one of them has to be `U` for the most part. One exception is `AA`, where both branches added different files.

Comment: Lol yea, it looks like you got it :)